# How to change height of UITextview in prototype cell when return key tapped?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview, ios-autolayout

I am working on an iOS application in which I am using a prototype cell and in this cell I am using a UITextView.

I am using auto-layout with storyboard and set constraints so that height of 
 cell should automatically change.

**I want the UITextView to resize the height so the text I'm typing fits inside it rather than you having to scroll to see the text that overflows. And tableview cell size should also be changed.**

This is my code:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var tableviewCart: UITableView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableviewCart.estimatedRowHeight = 142.0
        self.tableviewCart.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

[image]

```
class CartMenuItemCell:UITableViewCell{


    @IBOutlet weak var heightConstraintsFoodInstruction: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet var dishImageHeightConstraints: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var dishImageWidthConstraints: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var imgDishImageview: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var priceLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var bottomLabelHeightConstraints: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var addMenuItemView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var addMenuItemButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var menuItemCountLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var removeMenuItemButton: UIButton!    
}
```

[image]

Comment: After user finish with text edit, did you store that value somewhere?

Comment: Have you disabled scrolling of your `UITextView`? (I don't see it listed as an `IBOutlet` in the code you posted...)

Answer (score 0):

Your tableView configuration looks good.

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableviewCart: UITableView! {
    didSet {
        tableviewCart.estimatedRowHeight = 142.0
        tableviewCart.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
}
```

You just need to add a height constraint to textView named `textViewHeightConstraint` and set it equal to textView 'textView.contentSize.height'

```
textViewHeightConstraint.constant = textView.contentSize.height
```

And layout its `superview`
    textView?.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()